# Why does Rust need to know the code in module belong to whom?

Tags: rust

I encountered some problems [reading the Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch07-01-mod-and-the-filesystem.html):

> In this example, we have three modules again: `client`, `network`, and `network::client`. Following the same steps we did earlier for extracting modules into files, we would create *src/client.rs* for the `client` module. For the `network` module, we would create *src/network.rs*. But we wouldn’t be able to extract the `network::client` module into a *src/client.rs* file because that already exists for the top-level `client` module! If we could put the code for *both* the `client` and `network::client` modules in the *src/client.rs* file, Rust wouldn’t have any way to know whether the code was for `client` or for `network::client`

Why does Rust need to know the code in `client.rs` belongs to `client` or `network::client`? Can it belong to both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler has rules about where the source file for an external module can be. Those rules ensure that **there aren't two modules that use the same source file**.

If you really want to, you can override the rules with a `#[path]` [attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html):

```
mod client; // defaults to client.rs relative to the current file

mod network {
    #[path="client.rs"] // reads the same source as the outer `mod client;`
    mod client;
}
```

However, doing so would lead to duplicate code, i.e. the code in `client.rs` would be compiled twice, and everything that's defined in `client.rs` would be defined twice, in two separate modules. It's as if you made `network/client.rs` an exact copy of `client.rs` and didn't write the `#[path]` attribute.

Another thing you can do is provide an *alias* for a module by *reexporting* it elsewhere. This can be useful when building a library: it enables you to present an external module hierarchy that is different from the internal module hierarchy.

```
mod client; // not accessible externally

pub mod network {
    pub use client; // network::client::* will refer to the same definitions as client::*
}
```

For example, with the above, the `client` module is defined in `client.rs`, but clients use it through `my_crate::network::client`.